# Is it possible to create a excel file and fill results online Laravel PHP

Tags: php, excel, laravel, pdf

I am trying to export data of a specific user but they get messy, like this:
[image: Pic 1]
I dont want to add user name as many times as there is something else different from  above. in the pic above it added full name, email mobile role and status twice because it had two different timesheets, but a user can have many timesheets and I dont want it like that.

I am wondering if it is possible to create an example excel file, to have a different place just for the name, then different for mobile, and so on. something like this:

[image: pic 2]

or even in word/pdf file.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Why the second image doesn't work for you? how it is related to php, laravel, and pdf?

Comment: I want it to be like the second image, but it is like the first. the site is in PHP and laravel, but making it in pdf would work too

Comment: And what stops you? Sorry, it is not quite clear what problem you are facing. Please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic, https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Plugins are available for creating excel files
eg:
https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel

http://www.maatwebsite.nl/laravel-excel/docs/export

Comment: I am using maatwebsite.. but I dont get them how I want.. I just print data together, but now as I want them...